# Intercepting IBM's Watson Botkit middle-ware for testing

Tags: node.js, testing, mocking, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

My project uses the [botkit-middleware-watson](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/botkit-middleware) to talk to IBM Watson. Now I need to make a mock server for this Watson service.

This is just one line of code which calls Watson's API.

```
await watsonMiddleware.sendToWatsonAsync(bot, msg, null);
```

My question is, how can I intercept the API call and re-direct the call to my Watson Mock-Server?

Comment: Do you want to replace Watson Assistant by your mock server or just have the additional call?

Comment: @data_henrik I just need to have an end-2-end test which does not reply on the real Watson service. Not sure whether is it achievable?

Comment: That Watson botkit is just a plugin for an older version of botkit.ai (before it was bought). https://botkit.ai/docs/v0/middleware.html

Comment: hi @data_henrik thanks for your reply. I just just figured it out that I just need to provide some mock responses and that will be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

botkit-middleware-watson examples like [this one](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/botkit-middleware/blob/7d4efe90d2c8d8cb9b2ba8640fedd455efc15e38/examples/simple-bot/simple-bot-slack.js) show how `WatsonMiddleware` can be configured:

```
const WatsonMiddleware = require('botkit-middleware-watson').WatsonMiddleware;

const middleware = new WatsonMiddleware({
  iam_apikey: process.env.ASSISTANT_IAM_APIKEY,
  workspace_id: process.env.WORKSPACE_ID,
  url: process.env.ASSISTANT_URL || 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api',
  version: '2018-07-10'
});
```

...where `ASSISTANT_URL` is set in `.env`. This seems to be a place where to configure the URL of the mock server/simulator.

Another option could be for botkit to call the simulator as HTTP proxy, *if* the simulator you are using supports running as HTTP proxy.

Comment: thanks, this is what I have done for mocking it. it works :)